# pyspark - error reading parquet files - Could not read or convert schema for file

Tags: pyspark, parquet, change-data-capture

When trying to read parquet-files in databricks using pyspark I receive the following error:

```
parquet_df = spark.read.format("parquet").option("mergeSchema", "true").load("dbfs:/.../*.parquet")
java.io.IOException: Could not read or convert schema for file: dbfs:/.../xxx.parquet
```

Data is ingested to the adls container using Qlik Replicate.
So within a folder we have an initial load and continous changes.
Files within the folder look like:

```
20230328-041228351.parquet
20230328-071001565.parquet 
LOAD00000001.parquet
```

Reading in a single file or the whole folder both throw the same error.
With or without MergeSchema also does not change anything.
I worry the files might be corrupted but I thought I gave it a change and ask if someone here has another idea.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think files got corrupted, Could you try to **set this option** and try to read the files?

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles", "true")
```

Another way would be **create the parquet table** on top of the directory where your parquet files presented now then do a MSCK repair table.

```
%sql

CREATE TABLE t1 (name STRING, age INT) USING parquet
  LOCATION "/tmp/namesAndAges.parquet";

MSCK REPAIR TABLE t1
```

https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-repair-table.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. In this case that wasn't the issue though

Answer (score 0):

So the problem basically occured because our data had columns with the type "timedelta64[ns]". Qlik is using a hadoop when writing parquet which supports this datatype. PySpark is not able to handle this parquet datatype. Hence the error when reading in.

**Solution**

1. Providing a schema manually works
2. Reading in the data using pandas with fastparquet (not a solution for doing actual work in databricks but at least nice validate that data is not corrupted). PyArrow does not work btw.
3. Specific to Qlik: Use transformations to change the datatype so type is not used when writing the parquet files in the first place